# More efficient way to iterate through columns of flattened 2D Vec

Tags: indexing, rust, iterator

So I have a `Vec<bool>` stored in `self.board.data` that represents a 2D grid. It's easy to iterate through it row by row and convert between its index and x,y coordinates, but to index it column by column I need to use nested `for` loops. Is there a more efficient way to do this? I have functions similar to this one that will be run a *bunch* of times so I want to make them as efficient as possible.

```
    ///returns average height of all columns
    fn calc_avg_height(&self) -> f32 {
        let mut heights = 0;
        for x in 0..self.board.width {
            for y in 0..self.board.height {
                if self.board.data[(y*self.board.width)+x] {
                    heights+=self.board.height-y;
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        heights as f32/self.board.width as f32
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Playing around your example, I was very surprised to see that
the index computation (`y*width+x`) does not seem to be
simplified by the optimiser.
Moreover, I though the memory access was much more significant
than the removed multiplication in index computation.
But when it comes to timing I can see a substantial difference
(with various grid sizes and true/false initialisations).

**edit**

After reading some comments below, I compared the two versions,
`_v1` and `_v2`, in the compiler explorer (godbolt).
They look very similar except that `_v1` uses the `lea`
instruction and `_v2` uses `add` and `inc` instead.
According to vtune-amplifier, most of the time of `_v1` is
spent on this exact `lea` instruction.
So, at least on my computer, and on this specific example, and
counter-intuitively, the choice of `lea` instead of `add` and
`inc` seems more detrimental than the irregular memory access
pattern.

```rust
/*
  $ rustc -C opt-level=3 prog.rs && ./prog
  avg1=50.5
    v1: 4453 ms
  avg2=50.5
    v2: 2361 ms
*/

pub struct Board {
    width: usize,
    height: usize,
    data: Vec<bool>,
}

impl Board {
    pub fn new(
        width: usize,
        height: usize,
    ) -> Self {
        Self {
            width,
            height,
            data: vec![false; width * height],
        }
    }

    pub fn calc_avg_height_v1(&self) -> f32 {
        let mut heights = 0;
        for x in 0..self.width {
            for y in 0..self.height {
                if self.data[(y * self.width) + x] {
                    heights += self.height - y;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        heights as f32 / self.width as f32
    }

    pub fn calc_avg_height_v2(&self) -> f32 {
        let mut heights = 0;
        for x in 0..self.width {
            let mut idx = x;
            for y in 0..self.height {
                if self.data[idx] {
                    heights += self.height - y;
                    break;
                }
                idx += self.width;
            }
        }
        heights as f32 / self.width as f32
    }
}

pub fn run<F>(
    name: &str,
    repeat: usize,
    fnct: F,
) -> u128
where
    F: Fn() -> f32,
{
    let mut prev = -1.0_f32;
    let warmup = repeat / 10;
    for _ in 0..warmup {
        let avg = fnct();
        if avg != prev {
            println!("{}={}", name, avg);
            prev = avg;
        }
    }
    let now = std::time::Instant::now();
    for _ in 0..repeat {
        let avg = fnct();
        if avg != prev {
            println!("{}={}", name, avg);
            prev = avg;
        }
    }
    now.elapsed().as_millis()
}

pub fn main() {
    let mut board = Board::new(100, 100);
    for y in 0..board.height {
        for x in 0..board.width {
            board.data[y * board.width + x] = x == y;
        }
    }
    let repeat = 1_000_000;
    println!(
        "  v1: {} ms",
        run("avg1", repeat, || board.calc_avg_height_v1())
    );
    println!(
        "  v2: {} ms",
        run("avg2", repeat, || board.calc_avg_height_v2())
    );
}
```

Comment: oh thank you! this is really good to know. i just went through and implemented the new indexing technique in the module im currently optimizing and wow did it make a difference. to put it in perspective: im doing 1000 batch tests over a threadpool with 10 threads in it. using Vec<Vec<bool>> it would take 6m15s~ to complete. after i switched to Vec<bool> it shot up to 15 minutes. but now that ive implemented your technique for indexing it went down to 5m30s.

Comment: Your benchmark is erroneous, it does not take caching effects into account and it is difficult to do so. Rust does provide utils for benchmarking, use them to get comparable results. Also, as already written, the computation of the index is almost a noop, probably getting turned into a single lea instruction. Memory access is where one can optimize.

Comment: 'let mut idx = x;' shouldn't it be 'let mut idx = (y * self.width) + x'??? Obviously picking an idx like this would produce a better timing result, and a completly wrong computational result.

Comment: nah hes right. im iterating columns so it would start out at y0 then for each inner loop it increases by one y level. plus i have checks to make sure that the predicted result and actual result match up and so far they have 100% of the time using it.

also i should mention, the threadpool thing isnt meant to be a benchmark. thats just how the program im working on runs. im aware of rusts benchmarking features and ive been using them along the way. i figured id just give the overall result to add some perspective to the effect it made

Comment: @KonstantinW As stated in the text of my answer, I had the same intuition as yours and that's why I posted this answer that contradicts this intuition. Concerning `idx`, sorry, but I don't understand your objection; the idea was to trade a multiplication for an addition, and I think this formulation gives the exact same sequence of indices.

Comment: I am sorry, I overlooked the addition step. The performance difference is interesting, I guess this is due to the small size of the board which fits into L1 as a whole, then slow multiplication for index calculation matters. I dont know how the board is used in code later on, but it smells like a huge performance improvement could be achived by caching/updating the result and not recalculating it every time.

Answer (score 2):

Reading data column by column is going to be slow no matter what you do, since you will be jumping in memory. Computing the indexes is noise compared to that.

> Is there a more efficient way to do this?

One idea is putting bits together to reduce memory by 8. Another is keeping your data column by column and only update when required (this depends on your access patterns).

Comment: This is the correct answer. A popular crate for bit vectors is "bit-vec". Keeping two vectors for row and column to sum up the length in addition to the bit-vec field should give the best possible performance for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could preload the indexes so then you just need to iterate over them. Which may be more efficient in time but not in space:

```rust
fn preload_indexes(row_size: usize, column_size: usize) -> Vec<usize> {
    let mut indexes = Vec::new();
    for x in 0..row_size {
        for y in 0..column_size {
            let i = y*row_size+x;
            indexes.push(i);
        }
    }
    indexes
}
```

As a full example:

```rust
use std::fmt::Display;

struct Matrix<T: Display> {
    row_size: usize,
    column_size: usize,
    data: Vec<T>,
    columns_indexes: Vec<usize>,
}


fn preload_indexes(row_size: usize, column_size: usize) -> Vec<usize> {
    let mut indexes = Vec::new();
    for x in 0..row_size {
        for y in 0..column_size {
            let i = y*row_size+x;
            indexes.push(i);
        }
    }
    indexes
}

impl<T: Display> Matrix<T> {
    fn new(data: Vec<T>, row_size: usize, column_size: usize) -> Self {
        assert_eq!(data.len(), row_size*column_size);
        
        Self {
            row_size,
            column_size,
            data,
            columns_indexes: preload_indexes(row_size, column_size),
        }
    }
    
    fn print_rows(&self) {
        for e in self.data.iter() {
            println!("{}", e);
        }
    }
    
    fn print_columns(&self) {
        for i in self.columns_indexes.iter() {
            println!("{}", self.data[*i]);
        }
    }
}


fn main() {
    let matrix = Matrix::new(vec![1, 2, 3, 4], 2, 2);
    println!("Rows");
    matrix.print_rows();
    println!("Columns");
    matrix.print_columns();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=12199480e2d92fbae2240a6df3c362a3)

Comment: Reading trivial indexes from cache is likely slower than computing them. If they are not in cache, it is definitely slower.